# How to enable custom http module for a particular controller in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, httpmodule

I have a third party custom authentication HTTP module. I would like this module to configured to particular action method of a controller. Is this possible?

I know we can configure at folder level by having appropriate web.config at folder level, but I am looking for particular action method of particular controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't enable a Http module to a particular controller, but you can enable it to a particular request path in web.config. That effectively does the job imo. The following web.config snippet enables "ThirdParty.HttpModule" only for request that match the "yourController" path. This should work with MVC, WebForms, and generic handlers as well.

```
<location path="yourController" inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="yourModule" type="ThirdParty.HttpModule"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

The `inheritInChildApplications` part is important, if you have any other applications in subdirectories of this application, because child applications would inherit this configuration by default, and you may not want this module to work in child applications.

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbkh9s7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Note that the VS development server does not use http modules; you'll have to switch to IIS Express for development.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for action filters. There are numerous samples available on the web demonstrating how to set them up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609%28v=VS.98%29.aspx

Comment: Im not looking action filters. As I said in the question I have to use third party developed custom HTTP module.

Comment: I do not believe that's possible.  Action filters are the only way to do what you're wanting to achieve in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ActionFilters for that.
If you really want to use a HttpModule, then the module has to check if it should execute its logic based on the URL.
The HttpModule does not know anything about your controllers and vice versa.

Comment: As I mentioned in question, I have to use third party custom HTTP module. I do not have control on that.

Comment: Then another possibility would be, to wrap it into another HttpModule that only gets executed if a certain URL is requested.